# Vue calendar set at 6 months as default but will not update when user selects new date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a calendar in Vue that is set to default date of 6 months from today. It should only allow the users to select a date within those 6 months. Currently it is doing that but the issue is the user can't select a date from the calendar, I feel like the issue is with the default date being set to 6 months out but I have not figured out how to fix this so the user can select a different date and it populate on the calendar.

Here is my currect code

```
 <v-menu
                        v-model="removalDateMenu"
                        :close-on-content-click="false"
                        transition="scale-transition"
                        offset-y
                        nudge-top="400"
                        max-width="290px"
                        min-width="290px"
                    >
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                        <v-text-field
                            v-model="computedRemovalDateFormatted"
                            label="Removal Date"
                            required
                            prepend-icon="event"
                            :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Removal Date is required']"
                            readonly
                            v-on="on"
                        ></v-text-field>
                        </template>
                        <v-date-picker
                        v-model="jobs.selectedJob.removalDate"
                        no-title
                        @input="removalDateMenu = false"
                        :min="minSelectableDate"
                        :max="maxSelectableDate"
                        ></v-date-picker>
                    </v-menu>

data () {
        return {
 removalDateMenu: false,
      computedRemovalDateFormatted: '',
      jobs: {
        selectedJob: {
          removalDate: null, // Initially set to null
        },
      },
}},
computed: {
   minSelectableDate() {
            const today = new Date();
            return this.formatDate(today);
        },
        maxSelectableDate() {
            const today = new Date();
            const maxDate = new Date(today);
            maxDate.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 6);
            return this.formatDate(maxDate);
        },
}
 methods:{
        formatDate(date) {
            return date.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
        },
}
 created() {
        // Set the default removalDateMenu to 6 months from today
        const today = new Date();
        const defaultDate = new Date(today);
        defaultDate.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 6);
        this.computedRemovalDateFormatted = this.formatDate(defaultDate);
    },
```

I am expecting for the user to be able to select a different date within the 6 months allowed.

Comment: I think you should use the `@input` event handler fo `v-date-picker` to update the `computedRemovalDateFormatted`. I didn't see where you update the that variable, you just set the value on the created function. And why you use `v-model` with `job.selectedJob.removalDate`?